# Update table rows with incremental number within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to update a table so that rows of the same 'group' (Code + Color in the example) get an incremental number within the group. Rows for each group should be numbered 1, 2, 3...

```
id   | Code | Color   |Required_New_field
--------------------------
1231 |001   |Red      | 1
1232 |001   |Red      | 2
1233 |002   |Red      | 1
1234 |001   |Red      | 3
1235 |001   |Blue     | 1
1236 |002   |Red      | 2
1237 |001   |Blue     | 2
1238 |002   |Blue     | 1
1239 |002   |Red      | 3
...
```

In the example rows with Code=001 and Color=Red should get 1, 2, 3 respectivelly.

I've tried several approaches using subqueries and 'group by', but I realize is not actually the right way.

Any hint will be apprecciated!

**Edited:**
ROW_NUMBER() answers are great! Sadly I have to run it on an old sql_server 2000 version. And ROW_NUMBER() is available on 2005 and above (details on availability [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)). Any alternatives?

Comment: You can genarate a value using `row_number()` function, and expire the old records

Comment: why you will want to update,when you can just show it where require.what is the real scenario like ?

Comment: SQL Server **2005** is **no longer supported** (not even by "extended support") anymore - that alone should get you to **upgrade!**

Comment: @KumarHarsh: Required_New_field are initially empty. I want to update it to number the items for each group.

Comment: I know @marc_s! And completely agree with you! But in this case is not up to me. :(

Comment: ROW_NUMBER ***IS*** available in SQL Server **2005** - see e.g. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3572301/RowNumber-function-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm or https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1944/sql-server-2005-and-2008-ranking-functions-rownumber-and-rank/ - I guess Microsoft doesn't show that version anymore since it's left any form of support by now and is considered **legacy** (to put it mildly)

Comment: You're right @marc_s. It works on 2005. I've just -sadly- realized that the db I'm working on is a sql_server 2000 version. :( May be dinosaurs used it... Sorry for my mistake

Comment: I replaced the wrong `sql-server-2005` tag by `sql-server-2000`. It would have made a great difference for many people if the correct tag was mentioned in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I do agree with everyone from comments that `ROW_NUMBER()` was available in SQL Server 2005, here is alternative solution using a sub-query to `COUNT()`. Can be used on SQL Server 2000. Mind that, performance-wise, it's much more costly:

```
SELECT 
    t2.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM your_table t1 
     WHERE t1.code = t2.code 
       AND t1.color = t2.color
       AND t1.id <= t2.id) AS Rn
FROM 
    your_table t2
```

EDIT - For update:

```
UPDATE t2 
SET RN = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM your_table t1 
          WHERE t1.code = t2.code 
            AND t1.color = t2.color
            AND t1.id <= t2.id) 
FROM your_table t2
```

Comment: Given the new situation (sql server 2000) this is the only answer... I am deleting mine and upvoting this.

Comment: Even though the ROW_NUMBER() solutions are the best ones, this is the only one working in sql-server 2000. Thanks everyone for all answers and comments.

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate the number using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by code, color order by id) as required_new_field
from t;
```

For an update, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
       select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by code, color order by id) as seqnum
       from t
      )
update toupdate
    set required_new_field = seqnum;
```

Comment: I hadn't realized that a CTE is updatable, upvoting!

Comment: The answer is great! Sadly I have to run it on an old sql_server 2005 version. And ROW_NUMBER() is available on 2008 and above. Any alternatives?

Comment: row_number is available on 2005 as well,the above code works on 2005

Comment: You're right @TheGameiswar. It works on 2005. I've just -sadly- realized that the db I'm working on is a sql_server 2000 version. :( May be dinosaurs used it... Sorry for my mistake